# How many tasks can be submitted to ThreadPoolExecutor in Python

Tags: python, pyspark

I am writing a simple script to process some orders(varies from 1000-2000) in pyspark python in every run, Each order is taking roughly `3 seconds`(it includes API calls, D/B read, and D/B update, and other processing).
 To reduce the overall script time and  I updated the script with `Future` and `ThreadPoolExecutor` as there is no dependency among orders to process.

*Currently, I have created a ThreadPool of 20 threads and submitting all my tasks(1000 orders), and is working fine.

 I want to know how many tasks can I submit to **ThreadPoolExecutor** safely? Is there a point/number after which tasks will be rejected?*

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

futuresList = []
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(20)
start_seconds = time.time()

for tempOrder in membership_orders_to_processList:
  future = executor.submit(processOrder, (tempOrder))
  futuresList.append(future)
  
for tempFuture in futuresList:
  try:
    print("result",tempFuture.result())
  except Exception as inst:
    print("Exception occurred in future result",inst)

    
executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

Comment: I dont know about the exact limit, but i guess python is not Thread safe. You should instead use ProcessPoolExecutor which uses multiprocesiing instead of multithreading

Comment: What do you consider "submit safely"? You have created a ``ThreadPoolExecutor(20)``, so 20 tasks can *run* at once. You can still queue up as many as there is memory to hold them.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Is there a way we can conclude/dervie to some number here instead of depending on the memory

Comment: I don't think so. This would require estimating the size of work items, which is notoriously difficult (due to interning, lazy objects, etc). It is certainly not possible without a concrete description of what your work items actually are.

Answer (score -3):

Great question, It is different on every computer(processor, OS).
From my Experience, there isn't limit, because limit is, how many can handle OS.